# How to reach the data from Redux devtool?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to reach the data of 'audience' under an endpoint where it shows in Redux dev tool of Google Chrome.

Is it possible to reach it like we reach the localStorage, or Cookies section with using like 'window.localStorage' or how to do that?

I have some experience with Redux but still on the beginning.

[image]

Comment: If the data is stored in the redux state, why do you want it to be accessed from the localstorage? You can simply import the useSelector hook from react-redux package and select by `const audience = useSelector((state) => state.data.audience);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TirthTrivedi. That is what exactly I am experiencing. When I do that, I only get a function call and there is nothing inside. When I log it into the console, here is the output ```ƒ audience(state) { return state.data.audience; }```

Comment: Hey @osmancalisir, can you share your code snippet as well as the redux related files, just the store conf file will do.